# In Apache spark SQL can we roll back the transactions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make spark sql for data persistent, in that case can I use roll back data what we have persisted. Ex.

let say we have 3 tables t1,t2 and t3.
t1 and t2 table data is persisted successfully but some how t3 failed in data integrity level. so can I roll back t1 and t2 data wt I have persisted.

I mean can I roll back a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Spark code (v1.6.2 up to v2.1.0), there doesn't even seem to be an option to specify *when* to commit, nor rollback.

Assuming you save/write a Dataframe, eventually `savePartition` gets called and ends with:

```
  if (supportsTransactions) {
    conn.commit()
  }
```

Source:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L602-L604

You can always look into adding this feature yourself in the source code :) (and pull-request upstream!)